# how to make a multiple line table with xtable, longtable

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to to use xtable() and the longtable environment to display a multi=page table.

Currently when you run the code it will show "\scalebox " at the top and then it will cutoff columns of the table.

How do you remove the "\scalebox" at the top and show all the column in a readable manner?

Thank you.

here is the code:

````
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
keep_tex: TRUE
setspace: singlespacing
geometry: margin=1.1cm
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{color}
  - \usepackage{amsmath}
  - \usepackage{xcolor}
  - \usepackage{colortbl}
  - \usepackage{tabulary}
  - \usepackage{tabularx}
  - \usepackage{longtable}
  - \usepackage{ltxtable}
fig.lp: ('';character)
fig.pos: "H"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE  , comment = NA, message= FALSE, warning = FALSE)
```

```{r one, include= FALSE}

n=600
table = data.frame(name = rep(" dakjf aslkj dklsfj aslj ldjs",n), 
NUMERICFIELDNUMBERa = rep(10000,n),
NUMERICFIELDNUMBERb = rep(10000,n),
NUMERICFIELDNUMBERc = rep(10000,n),
NUMERICFIELDNUMBERd = rep("1250 + 52.33",n),
NUMERICFIELDNUMBERe = rep("25.6 + 36.25",n),
NUMERICFIELDNUMBERf = rep(10000,n),
NUMERICFIELDNUMBERg = rep(10000,n)
)

head(table)

    colnames(table) = c("GROUP NAME",
                               "Numeric Field Number1",
                              "Numeric Field Number2",
                               "Numeric Field Number3",
                                "Numeric Field Number4",
                            "Numeric Field Number5",
                              "Numeric Field Number6",
                          "Numeric Field Number7"
                      ) 
rownames(table) = NULL

```


```{r echo= FALSE, comment = FALSE, message= FALSE, warning = FALSE, results='asis'} 

library(xtable)
options(xtable.include.rownames=F) 
options(xtable.scalebox=.7)
#options(xtable.tabular.environment = "tabulary")
#options(xtable.width = "7in")
options(xtable.comment=F)
options(xtable.floating = F)
t = xtable(table)
#align(t)= "cccccccc"#"cp{2cm}cp{2cm}cp{2cm}cp{2cm}cp{2cm}cp{2cm}cp{2cm}cp{2cm}" #rep("p{2cm}C",8)#"p{1cm}cccccccc"
#align(t) = "cp{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}"
print(t, sanitize.text.function = identity)


```
````